# Next js Head doesn't access public folder?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Head in a very straightforward way

```
import Head from "next/head";

const HeadTags = () => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css" />    
      <title>this works</title>
    </Head>
  </>
);
export default HeadTags;
```

The title does change, but the styles.css file is not having an effect therefore not imported from the public folder. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Import global css in your _app file instead.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-stylesheets-in-head-component